# Not showing embedded images email in outlook client C#

Tags: c#, outlook

**I've this method to send email with images embedded in a body text and it works in almost all clients, except in Outlook. It doesn't show the images outlook but it does in outlook web. Someone help?
The images are in on directory called images
here you have the method**

```
  public static void SendNotificationMail(string subject, string message, string emailTo, string ccTo, string bccTo, string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create a message and set up the recipients.
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress(AppConfig.EmailFrom, AppConfig.EmailFromDisplayName);
            msg.To.Add(emailTo);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ccTo))
            {
                msg.CC.Add(ccTo);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(bccTo))
            {
                msg.Bcc.Add(bccTo);
            }

            msg.Subject = subject;
            msg.Body = message;


            String imagesPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "images";
            String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(imagesPath);

            foreach(String imageFile in files){

                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(imageFile);

                // create the INLINE attachment
                Attachment inline = new Attachment(file.FullName);
                inline.ContentDisposition.Inline = true;
                inline.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = DispositionTypeNames.Inline;
                inline.ContentId = "@"+file.Name;
                inline.ContentType.MediaType = "image/jpg";
                inline.ContentType.Name = Path.GetFileName(imageFile);


                msg.Attachments.Add(inline);
               contentID);

            }
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(AppConfig.SMTPServer);
            client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

            try
            {
                Utility.PrintMessage("Sending notification e-mail to: " + emailTo);

                client.Send(msg);

                Logger.WriteTNSLog(subject + " - " + emailTo);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.WriteAppLog(e.Message, "Utility.SendNotificationMail()");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

(I got this same issue trying to embed a file in an email body... In the end I had to put the Image in a byte array, and go from there:)

As I said, put your image raw data in a Byte Array `imageByteArray`, and image filename (with extension) in a String `imageName`. Then, attach it like this (I chose imageCid arbitrarily as the 'cid' for the attachment)

```
... 
mail.Body = "<html><body><div style='text-align:center'><img src=""cid:imageCid"" style=""margin:0 auto;""/></body></html>";
mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(New MemoryStream(imageByteArray), imageName));
mail.Attachments(0).ContentId = "imageCid";
...
smtp.Send(mail);
```

I'm more a VB guy, so maybe you have to change it a bit. Anyways, I think I made it understandable :)

Comment: SOrry @D le
I didn't get you. :-/

Comment: which part? For starters, transform your image into a byte array and put it into 'imageByteArray'. Then, put your image name (with extensión) as a string in 'imageName'. 
The rest is self-explanatory I think, if you still don't know what to do, comment it specifying your doubts